# организация модели ветвления в git bash

Tags: git, github

У меня на visual studio в одном проекте есть 3 файла с кодом. Мне нужно в командной строке(git bash) организовать модель ветвления, где каждый файл - отдельная ветка. Это нужно сделать локально, просто в командной строке. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать

Comment: `каждый файл - отдельная ветка` - это значит, что есть три ветки и в каждой есть только один из этих файлов?

Comment: да, вы правильно поняли

Comment: ну просто возьмите и сделайте, и не спрашивайте ни у кого разрешения. у вас возникли какие-то трудности при выполнении? тогда изложите их в тексте вопроса, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В вопросе и интересующей автора задаче я вижу, как минимум, 2 его методологические ошибки:

- на русском SO не осталось реальных знатоков VCS в общем и Git в частности;
- вместо того чтобы решать **реальную бизнес-задачу**, решается затык "я хочу сделать так, *заделайте мне* решение" (я не могу придумать ситуацию, в которой для **3 уже контролируемых** объектов надо организовывать раздельный поштучный, так что что именно требуется решить таким экзотическим извратом - лучше излагать прямым текстом)
- совершенно проигнорировано обычное требование "знать матчасть используемого инструментария", потому что с таким знанием вопрос не возникал бы вообще: 1) бранч в Git это указатель на отдельный changeset 2) любой changeset версионирует **все** (новые) изменения во **всех** объектах репозитория общим срезом (а не отдельных файлов, как было при царе Горохе в CVS).

Так что из пп. 1 и 2 последней ошибки следует - *"не получится сделать однофайловые бранчи так, чтобы потом при слиянии их это не вылезло боком"*. Точка. А если не предполагается пост-слияния, то очевидный вопрос "А на хрена тогда вообще бранчинг городить?"

Переосмыслите *реальную* задачу (или переспросите заказчика), с вменяемой формулировкой перезадайте вопрос и, возможно, получите более полный ответ.

HTH